# Can I use Q_PROPERTY or Q_INVOKE in class that no derivered from QObject?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

So I need to use some macroses to integrate my c++ code with qml but I really dont know if I can use Q_PROPERTY or Q_INVOKE without derivering my class from QObject and without using Q_OBJECT macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to put `Q_PROPERTY` in a struct, when also declaring it as a `Q_GADGET`, but without changed-signals. And according to [Exposing Q_INVOKABLE in Q_GADGET to QML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65135839/exposing-q-invokable-in-q-gadget-to-qml) it also seems possible to put a Q_INVOKABLE on a Q_GADGET.